# Проблемы с настройкой сервера после переноса АД

Tags: windows, dns, ldap

Добрый день!

Есть сеть около 70 компьютеров и 2 сервера. Старый и вновь установленный. Сейчас они должны работать: Новый как основной, старый как вспомогательный.

```
старый сервер: 192.168.0.1 S1.domen.comновый сервер: 192.168.0.2 S2.domen.comроутер: 192.168.0.3
```

После переноса АД на новый сервер начались проблемы с DNS. Сейчас при проверке утилитой netdiag на новом сервере выдает ошибки:

> `Netcard queries test . . . . . . . : Passed    [WARNING] The net card '╠шэшяюЁЄ WAN (IP) - Teefer2 Miniport' may not be working because it has not received any packets.    GetStats failed for '╧Ё ьющ ярЁрыыхы№э√щ яюЁЄ'. [ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]    [WARNING] The net card '╠шэшяюЁЄ WAN (PPTP)' may not be working because it has not received any packets.    [WARNING] The net card '╠шэшяюЁЄ WAN (PPPoE)' may not be working because it has not received any packets.    [WARNING] The net card '╠шэшяюЁЄ WAN (IP)' may not be working because it has not received any packets.    GetStats failed for '╠шэшяюЁЄ WAN (L2TP)'. [ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]`
>
> `Domain membership test . . . . . . : Failed    [WARNING] Ths system volume has not been completely replicated to the localmachine. This machine is not working properly as a DC.`
>
> `DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed    PASS - All the DNS entries for DC are registered on DNS server '192.168.0.0' and other DCs also have some of the names registered.    [WARNING] The DNS entries for this DC are not registered correctly on DNS server '192.168.0.3'. Please wait for 30 minutes for DNS server replication.`
>
> `LDAP test. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed    [WARNING] Failed to query SPN registration on DC 'S1.domain.com'.    [WARNING] Failed to query SPN registration on DC 'S2.domain.com'.`

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?

Может ли от этого временами пропадать доступ к некоторым сайтам (в частности google)? Иногда нет доступа с компьютеров сети на расшареные ресурсы сервера, под учетной записью администратора нет доступа на каталоги других машин.

Answer (score 2):

1. Как переносился домен
2. Проверить DNS
3. Может ли от этого временами пропадать доступ к некоторым сайтам - да